# Python: why are lists defined inside while loops recycled but not variables that are assigned lists inside same loop?

Tags: python, function, append

Still new, I searched google but I didn't really find an explanation so thank you in advance.  When writing Python, why is is that during a while loop, a variable that is assigned a list outside of the while loop can be modified and retain it's modifications with each iteration, but a variable that is assigned a list during the loop will revert back to it's original assignment with each iteration?  Here is an example code:

```
x = [1,1,1]

while True:
    a = [1,1,1]
    b = x
    a.append(1)
    b.append(2)
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

why does variable a stay the same, while variable b can be appended with each iteration and maintain its modifications?  Thanks.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Because `a` is overwritten with a new list, whilst `b` is assigned the same list (which keeps a separate reference as `x`).

Comment: You assign a reference (not really, but in effect) to variable `x` in the variable `b` so whenever you use `b` you're essentially writing to `x`. On the other hand, `a` is assigned as a new list in each loop so there's nothing to keep its previous state.

Comment: @ekhumoro with you and zwer's comments I think it has begun to make sense to me

Comment: @zwer thanks, I didn't connect that list b is essentially writing to x because once you're out of the loop I think x remains unchanged?  So it didn't occur to me, thanks!

Comment: I toyed around and it looks like the original list is actually being changed, or the original list that variable x is referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Since `b` and `x` are references to the same list object, your code is equivalent to

```
x = [1,1,1]

while True:
    a = [1,1,1]
    a.append(1)
    x.append(2)
    print(a)
    print(x)
```

In each iteration of the loop, the list referenced by `x` gains another element. `a` is a reference to a new 3-element list in each iteration, though, so it never gets bigger than 4 elements before being discarded. It's easier to see if you unroll the (original) loop:

```
x = [1,1,1]

a = [1,1,1]  # new list
b = x        # reference to old list
a.append(1)
b.append(2)
print(a)
print(b)

a = [1,1,1]  # new list
b = x        # reference to old list
a.append(1)
b.append(2)
print(a)
print(b)

...
```

You can also sprinkle in a few calls to `print(id(a))` and `print(id(b))` to see that `id(b)` never changes, while `id(a)` changes in each iteration. (Due to how the garbage collector works, `id(a)` will probably oscillate back and forth between 2 distinct values, though.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner, seeing the code visually roll for a second iteration helps

Answer (score 0):

It's because `a` is redefined at each iteration, while `b` isn't. When you write `b = x`, you only link b to x, and modifying `b` in your loop is in fact changing only the list that it refers to, the same list that `x` refers to which isn't redefined at each iteration (unlike `a`).

Comment: More of a comment vice answer; see other comments for cause

Comment: Yea, you're right, I can't comment tho on main post @pstatix

Comment: @JeanRostan  Somewhat misleading.  When you append to `b` you aren't changing `x`.  You are changing the list that `b` and `x` both refer to.  If you set `b` to a new value, like `b = 0`, then `x` would not be changed.

Comment: @stark you're right, I'll try to change the wording, my bad.

Comment: Thanks @JeanRostan your comments have been enlightening, and I'm a little disappointed I didn't realize this sooner.

Comment: @stark thanks for the clarification, it's good to know what's going on behind the scenes so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic case of Shallow Copy vs Deep Copy.

This code below will give you results as expected by you.

```
import copy
x = [1,1,1]

while True:
    a = [1,1,1]
    b = copy.deepcopy(x)
    a.append(1)
    b.append(2)
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Assignment statements by default do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object.

Shallow copy is by default.
To completely copy the values, we need deepcopy as shown in the above code

Comment: This isn't even a copy; it's just two references. A shallow copy would be `b = list(x)`.

Comment: @shadab.tughlaq I don't really know what a shallow or deep copy is, but I'll look into it thanks for introducing me to the concept